# gcloud created a new account when submitting a new SSH key-pair and now I cannot access the original one

Tags: ssh, debian, cloud, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I just started with the Google Cloud Platform and created my first VM instance (Debian).

It all worked in a pretty straight-forward way, I hit the SSH button next to my instance and it opened up a command-line interface in a new browser window. My username was the handle (pre-@) part of my gmail.

However, I wanted to use Terminal on my macbook as a CLI for accessing it. Looking at the guides, this seemed to be a long convoluted process. I followed this process (detailed below) but now I can only access some new account on the VM; the username is my full gmail address this time (but with underscores replacing non-alphabet characters, so like the orignal but with "_gmail_com" tacked on to the end). I can no longer access the original account that seems to be the proper account with admin privileges. Note that I can sudo into the root account and open up the directories and files owned by the original account but this seems very dumb.

I've tried posting in the forum for this stuff, Google's group for Google Compute, "gce-discussion", but my posts are held at approval for some reason. It's as though Google are just hoping I cave and pay for technical support.

My aim is to have a python session running a discord bot that continues while I log off. It'd also be good to be able to serve up files (images) via http.

Thank you for any help you can be!

The steps I followed in the convoluted process given in the guide are as follows:

- I created an SSH keypair (private and public)
- I downloaded and installed the Google SDK to get the gcloud CLI applciation
- I issued the gcloud command to set the public key up on my instance
- it had me log in at a google page (OAuth-like thing)
- I started an SSH session on Terminal, invoking the file containing my private key, trying with different permutations of options
- finally got it to connect and log in using my-handle_gmail_com (ie the second username on my instance)
- when I tried to access the SSH from within the Google Cloud Platform page, the browser-based CLI automatically logged my into this same second account, "my-handle_gmail_com". So now I have no access to the original.

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a good article ... see if this helps ... https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-compute-mastering-ssh/

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question - do you want to be able to click "SSH" button in the GCP console and be automatically logged in - right ?